# Comma in 1000 separate in Excel app does not work

Tags: macbook-pro

Even i check the box "use 1000 separate (,)" but nothing is shown in the number. Please Help[image]

Answer (score 1):

In System Preferences > Language & Region, you need to select the Region setting as "United States" instead of "United States (Computer)". You'll need to relaunch Excel after this.

[image]

This setting is required in Excel 2011 only. In Excel 2016, it works fine.